# AngularJS Bootstrap carousel slide data from base64 image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with the AngularJS Bootstrap carousel. As image source it is expecting an url to an image located somewhere. In my case the images to display in the carousel are stored in a MongoDB in base64 format. To retrieve the images I do a database call in my Angular Controller and as result I get an array with base64 images. Now I want to show these images in a Bootstrap carousel in my HTML. For this purpose I'm using the AngularJS Bootstrap Carousel. The code in the HTML file looks like this:

```
                <carousel interval="myInterval">
                    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}?{{$index}}" style="margin:auto;" />
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                            <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </slide>
                </carousel>
```

I already tried to create a blob from each image and then create an ObjectURL from the blob to convert it into an url as datasource for the carousel. But that didn't work because the carousel can't handle blob as image source. The code in my controller to generate the blob:

```
        angular.forEach(result, function(image) {
            var newWidth = 600 + $scope.slides.length + 1;
            var content = "data:" + image.contentType + ";base64," + image.body;
            var blob = new Blob([ content ], { type : image.contentType });
            var unsafeurl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
            var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(unsafeurl);
            $scope.slides.push({image: url + newWidth + '/300'});       
        });
```

Where result is the array with base64 images. How can I get the Angular Bootstrap carousel working with my base64 image source? Is this not posible with this kind of carousel or do I need to use the default Bootstrap carousel for usage with the base64 image array? I was also wondering if it is posible to create an image url instead of an object url because I think that could solve my problem.

Comment: No need to create a blob to display the image just use the constructed base64 image. In your case, `var content` has the constructed image so just assign it to a `$scope`. E.g. `$scope.slides.push({image: content});`. Note that I only assigned/pushed the `var content` into the `$scope.slides.image`.

Comment: @Alberto I.N.J. Thanks for your reply. Your solution work's fine in IE. But when I open the page in Chrome I get an error for each image in the carousel when it is loaded: 
GET data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMAAAACQCAYAAABeUmTwAAAAAXNSR…phWS+lsemVClYQVLlXG7gtWql/Cu3PPbjr/3/PtjjU7ozmnUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=602/300?1 net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Any idea how to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: Can you provide the content of your `image` object especially `image.body`?

Comment: The evidence object returned from the database looks like this:
body: "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAbkAAAF+CAYAAAAfuWQkAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAP+lSURBVHhe7L0HvF3Hed27Tj+334tOgAA7wd5EsXeJIiWqF6vQtizbkuPyS+..."
contentType: "image/png"
file: "imagefile.png"

Comment: Can you provide the full data `image.body`? I need to see if the dataUrl was properly formatted.

Comment: This is the full body: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADQAAAAuCAMAAABQ68okAAAAAXNSR0ICQMB9xQAAADNQTFRFAAAAf39/8t837do279w38d43/+s7/uo6++c69+M59OA4+OQ5/ek6+eU59uI4+uY5/Og6iCNEzwAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAE1pY3Jvc29mdCBPZmZpY2V/7TVxAAAAoUlEQVRIx+2USRYCIQwFo63+oBG5/2lleO2icchvh4WPWoVFEUgIIh/h0DEkv7TpkC/RjgRo2E7Tbn88KSHZOcYQw0WTvxAwTUktA4+EOReshj4JczKiTzeJau46Ce89I5QNSAmFNdKY3J9KteKUhDocGUKqjhr3IkQsZYw5XgnLrDN3anEbEq90d/FCerR6Ji2+DIe0LLGr5N0v7Mk0+BuurUoNzyEk2XIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: I've tried to see if the image.body that you provided is working but it's not. Can you double check if you properly converted the image to data url? You can check it to see if it's working if you construct the data url with the `data:image/jpg;base64,` and run it in your browser.

Comment: When I add an img source to my HTML file to display only the first result as a single image it works fine and it shows the image:
<img class="imgBorder" data-ng-src="{{ avatar }}">

controller:
var avatar = "data:" + result[0].contentType + ";base64," + result[0].body;
$scope.avatar = avatar;

Comment: But the data url that you had provided was not working so I guessed that the `image.body` data itself was not properly converted to data url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the HTML code for the carousel. I changed this line:

```
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}?{{$index}}" style="margin:auto;" />
```

To this line:

```
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" />
```

And now the carousel is working fine in both IE and Chrome.